# Input and output in Tensorflow lite model

Tags: java, android, tensorflow, kotlin, tensorflow-lite

I've train a model that have in input this tensor:
Input Shape: [ 1 50]
Input Type: <class 'numpy.float32'>

and in output this tensor:
Output Shape: [ 1 50 17]
Output Type: <class 'numpy.float32'>

How can I create these in java? for using this on Android device?Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are some TensorFlow Lite language bindings including Java and Kotlin for  Android application developments.

- Official TensorFlow Lite Java API is available. For the details, check out this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/android).
- The recent versions of Android Studio also deals with the TensorFlow Lite model files as the acceptable file assets.